# gevent.Timeout not raised

Tags: python, network-programming, timeout, gevent, monkeypatching

I have a server that does "some stuff" in a section and I have a "with gevent.Timeout(5)" around that. I have some checks going on in another greenlet and through that I noticed that one of the greenlets which did that "some stuff" was running for 45mins. I had to eventually restart the program to kill it (I know of other ways of killing it but that's not the problem..).

I monkey patching using gevent.monkey.patch_all() as well. The "some stuff" part does involve network connections and I am guessing something got stuck in one of those places. I don't understand why the timeout exception was not raised. Does anyone have any idea why the gevent.Timeout exception might not have been raised?

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I've used `gevent.Timeout`, I've also used it as a context manager but with the second argument `False`. This way the context manager suppresses any exception and just leaves the chunk of code. You can follow up by checking if, say, the block set a value successfully:

```
result = None
with gevent.Timeout(5, False):
    # Something that stalls

if result == None:
    # Take care of business
```

This has worked for me very reliably. It seems that the default second argument `exception` to `gevent.Timeout` is `None` -- have you tried replacing it with your own exception type? Or even `Exception`?

Comment: I think having second argument as False or None shouldn't make a difference? And after the with gevent.Timeout block, I had a return statement so obviously my code was stuck somewhere in that block. I couldn't have used the if result == None: statement. I am unable to produce the problem again locally. That was in a production server. I could try my own exception but I have to be able to produce the problem again and even if I can, I wonder my exception will be thrown at all because it it didn't timeout earlier in the first place.

Comment: A tale as old as time :-) FWIW, it took us a little time tinkering with `gevent.Timeout`, and in the end using `False` and checking for `None` in a result worked for us. If your network communication is http fetches, I can point you at some of our unit tests that can help you repro timeouts.

Comment: It's not a http request but a connection to the database and I have a strong feeling it's something to do with sockets. I found another bug in gevent related to socket timeouts if one uses makefile - [link](https://bitbucket.org/denis/gevent/commits/65968cf1baa9/). But sure, it would be helpful to check what your unit tests look like and if I can reproduce the problem locally. I don't see why using False should workout though. I should look into that again myself too maybe.